# Determining inflection point/ threshold values from a Cox regression using cubic splines

Tags: survival, cox-model, splines, threshold, medicine

I am interested in looking at the impact of time to diagnosis of cancer on death. I will be modelling time to dx as a continuous predictor using cubic splines. I am also interested in determining a threshold value that indicates the point where hazard of death is lowest, suggesting that a wait time beyond this point is detrimental to ones survival. I believe that this can be achieved by looking at the inflection point of the hazard function, or the point where the hazard is lowest and then starts increasing, but is there another way? Perhaps one that is more methodologically sound than a visual assessment?

I have briefly looked at the maximally selected rank statistic but am unsure if it applies to my situation. If there is a way to identify several thresholds, that would be of particular interest to me.